# Why is my XSLT fragment causing an error?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use the below code to check if my variable contains the word NOT_INTERFACED.
So I am using the ends-with function.

But if it does I want to print the remaining word minus NOT_INTERFACED.

But I am getting an error, my java program is calling this template however I get an exception ends-with not found.

Am I doing something wrong syntax wise ?

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="ends-with($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')"/>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ID_FO"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

and the error is

> COULD NOT FIND FUNCTION ENDS WITH. LOCATION: unknown
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: xsl:when test="ends-with($ID_FO,'_NOT_INTERFACED')"
  <XSL:value-of select="substring-before($ID_FOR,'_NOT_INTERFACED')"/>
</XSL:when

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? And are you using any extra XML parsing libraries (e.g. Xerces)?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153304

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: See my comment below,

I checked the XPATH 1.0 documentation and it does not include an ends-with function. You'll have to do the substring method I detailed below--that is if you are using XSLT 1.0 (which uses XPATH 1.0)

EDIT 2: Just so my comment has some nice syntax highlighting:

```
<xsl:when test="substring($ID_FO, string-length($ID_FO)-14) = '_NOT_INTERFACED'">
```

Comment: Ok, what version of XSLT are you using? I think ends-with might not be in 1.0 in which case you need to do a little more fancy footwork. Like substring($ID_FO, string-length($ID_FO)-15) = '_NOT_INTERFACED'... (check my indices because XSLT counts from 1 not 0 so I tend to make mistakes.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is actually -14 not -15. Since the string length is the number of characters which would be 15 if the string was simply _NOT_INTERFACED and the indices start at 1 so you want to subtract 14. I have no idea why they thought it was good to change stuff up on us programmers and start with 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT parsers are case sensitive - try using this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="ends-with($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')"/>
     </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$ID_FO"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Also you had forgotten to close the `xsl:when` element after the `test` attribute.

Comment: guys... no type error from my end... What I may have typed here was just to explain the logic m using. I am not making any syntax error... the error I get is funtions ends-with not found :(....\
Please help

Comment: Please post the actual code that is causing the error and the error you are seeing.

Comment: <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="ends-with($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED')"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>garbage</xsl:text>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

and the error is COULD NOT FIND FUNCTION ENDS WITH.
LOCATION: unknown java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Dire: you misunderstood the request. Please post the Java code you are using to try and run the xsl template against the xml document.

Comment: @Dire - have you noticed that you can actually *edit* your own post? Please do not post question clarifications in comments. And please use *real* code right from the start. No-one can help you with syntactically incorrect mock-ups your made up "to show the logic".

Answer (score 0):

I've already posted it as a comment in my answer over at [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153304). Replace your entire `<xsl:choose>` construct with this one-liner:

```
<xsl:value-of select="
  substring-before(concat($ID_FO, 'NOT_INTERFACED'), 'NOT_INTERFACED')
" />
```

You are still not clear whether your string *contains* or *ends with* `'NOT_INTERFACED'`.

If it *ends with* the substring you want to get rid of, use the above. If it *contains* it, you have your answer in the other question. I suggest having a second look there.