# Removing leading 0 in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have IDs that are coming through in XML files that are padded with zeros, such as:

```
<dog pet_id="00005">
```

When parsing this, I'd like to just get the integer `5`. Doing something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="dog/@pet_id" />
```

retrieves "00005"

What's the best way to do this to just get `5`?

Comment: Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153304/how-to-remove-particular-characters-from-a-string-using-xslt

Comment: Not really. The answer below helps, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="number(dog/@pet_id)" />
```

or if you need to convert back to a string:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string(number(dog/@pet_id))" />
```